# Getting URL from RSS Description

Tags: ios, objective-c, rss

I need help getting a URL from a RSS feed.  I'm trying to get the image URL from description but it's null when I try to use it.

Here is the feed:

```
<item>
<title>Photo</title>
<description>
<img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/c0d9f18c016c3bd45a84edc58d5c9d1b/tumblr_mv6nhvj0Vs1qjbzjlo1_500.jpg"/><br/><br/>
</description>
<link>
http://littleheartrecords.tumblr.com/post/64965673651
</link>
<guid>
http://littleheartrecords.tumblr.com/post/64965673651
</guid>
<pubDate>Thu, 24 Oct 2013 13:05:55 -0400</pubDate>
</item>
```

Here is where I get it:

```
else if ([elementName isEqual:@"description"])
    {
        currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        [self setInfoString:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"img src"]];
    }
```

And here is where I try to use it:

```
NSLog(@"infoString: %@", [item infoString]);
    NSURL *imageLink = [NSURL URLWithString:[item infoString]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageLink];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in `didStartElement:`

```
else if ([elementName isEqual:@"description"]) {
    ...
    isDescription = YES;
} else if ([elementName isEqual:@"img"]) {
    if (isDescription) {
         NSString *urlString = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"src"];
         NSLog(@"urlString : %@", urlString);
        [self setInfoString:urlString];
        //or
        [item setInfoString:urlString];
    }
}
```

and in `didEndElement:`

```
else if ([elementName isEqual:@"description"]) {
    ...
    isDescription = NO;
}
```

Comment: what `setInfoString:` method does.? try using `[item setInfoString:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"src"]];`

Comment: It still doesn't give me anything.

Comment: what about "NSLog" of "urlString"?

Answer (score 0):

Use [XMLReader](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader) classes as its very easy to use.

`Example` :

```
NSData *data = ...; // some data that can be received from rss
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data 
                                         options:XMLReaderOptionsProcessNamespaces 
                                           error:&error];
```

**Note** use `NSDictionary` returned from `classes` to get `url string`.